# How can I edit JPanel Graphics in one class?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm trying to program snake on a JFrame and doing all graphical stuff (moving the 'snake', random food generation, etc.) on a JPanel. I'm in the beginning stages so all I'm trying to do right now is move a black square around on my frame using arrow keys. My while loop in the Panel class won't get interrupted by a key press in the Snake class, so is there a way to edit JPanel graphics from the same class with all my other code?

Here's all the code. My Panel class at the bottom follows the template I found here.

```
public class Snake {

    // panel width and height
    static int pW; 
    static int pH;

    static int x = 10;
    static int y = 10;

    static int k;

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("SNAKE");

    // getters for panel class
    public int getPW() { return pW; }
    public int getPH() { return pH; }
    public int getX()  { return x;  }  
    public int getY()  { return y;  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // get screen dimensions
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int sH = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        int sW = (int) screenSize.getWidth();

        pW = (int) sW/2;
        pH = (int) sH/2;

        // initialize frame
        frame.setSize    (pW/1,pH/1);
        frame.setLocation(pW/2,pH/2);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                k = e.getKeyCode();

                switch(k) {

                case 38: /* y -= square size */ break; // up
                case 40: /* y += square size */ break; // down 
                case 37: /* x -= square size */ break; // left
                case 39: /* x += square size */ break; // right
                case 27: System.exit(0);

                }

            }
        });

        Panel panel = new Panel();

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    Snake snake = new Snake();

    //square size and separation between squares
    int sep = 0;
    int size = 50;

    // initial location of square on the panel/frame
    int x = sep + size;
    int y = sep + size;

    // holding values to check if x or y have changed
    int xH = x;
    int yH = x;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        int pW = snake.getPW();
        int pH = snake.getPH();

        int i; int o;

        Color on  = Color.BLACK;
        Color off = Color.GRAY;

        // gray background
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0,0,pW,pH);

        // black square initialization
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);

        /* this loop is supposed to check if the black
         * rectangle has moved by repeatedly grabbing x & y
         * values from the Snake class. When a key is pressed
         * and the values change, a gray rectangle is placed at the old location 
         * and a black one is placed at the new location.
         * 
         * When I run the program, I get stuck in this while loop.
         * If I had the while loop in the same class I check for keys,
         * I don't think I would have this problem
         */

        while(true) {

            x = snake.getX();
            y = snake.getY();

            if(x != xH || y != yH) {

            g.setColor(off);
            g.fillRect(xH, yH, size, size);
            g.setColor(on);
            g.fillRect(snake.getX(), snake.getY(), size, size);

            xH = x;
            yH = y;

        }}

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never have a `while(true)` loop in a painting method. This will just cause an infinite loop and your GUI will not be able to respond to events.

Instead you need to add methods to your snake class to move the snake. So when one of the arrow keys is pressed you update the starting position of the snake. Then the method will invoke repaint() and the snake will repaint itself when the paintComponent() method is invoked by Swing.

So your painting code should override `paintComponent()` not paint() and you should invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first statement in the method.

Don't call your custom class "Panel", there is an AWT class with that name. Make your class name more descriptive.